# Get username at the client with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

How do you use JQuery/javascript to get the username on the client side of an ASP .NET MVC application and post it back to the server for the controller to process?

I would like the following sequence of events to occur:

1. Get username of client machine.
2. Post username back to server.
3. Instantiate new object that takes the username in the constructor. (Using Ninject for DI)
4. Inject the object into the receiving controller.

Comment: Does your application have any sort of authentication?  If so, what kind? (for example forms, Windows)

Comment: Authentication is considered done as the user has logged onto the intranet (So Windows Authentication).

Answer (score 3):

On the client side of things, you shouldn't have access to the username.  You don't need it, either.  In your server-side code, you can access the Windows Authentication username with this code:

```
var username = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString();
```

Comment: So when I said Windows Authentication I meant when the user logs in using Active Directory on to the machine. Not onto the web server. How does the server machine know the client machine username? Is that information always posted via the HttpContext object?

Comment: You'll have to enable Windows authentication for your web site.  If your users are using IE, they should get automatically authenticated.  Other browsers may ask them to resubmit their username and password.

Answer (score 0):

To build on top of @Jacob answer, get the value in server side controller populate a viewmodel property with this value of variable username

```
    var username = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString();
vmUser.UserName = username; // Here vmUser is a sample ViewModel
```

In cshtml, if using razor engine use a hidden variable by using one of the constructs below

```
  @Html.Hidden or
   @Html.HiddenFor(um=>um.UserName)
```

to access it in Jquery or JavaScript
Hope this add on helps for newbies in mvc and jquery

Answer (score 0):

To add to the discussion here, we can get the username into a javascript variable as follows:

```
<text>var jsUser = '@HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString()';</text>
```